# Display custom post type for specific user

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, customization, custom-field

I hope you can help me ... I already searched the information but I did not find anything useful.

I am doing a project where I created a post type (student_valuation) where the administrator places information about a member (student), there is a dropdown (student_name) to choose the student name.

I want to put this evaluation in a specific page for the student that will be logged. If someone has a query I can use ... thank you.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for... What do you want to hide? The student list? The page? The whole post type?

Comment: Not understand the description but depends on the question title, you can wrap your wp_query in condition get_current_user_id().

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$args = array(
    'author' => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type' => 'YOUR_CUSTOMPOST_TYPE',
);
$author_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($author_posts->have_posts()): while ($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();

     //DISPLAY CONTENTS HERE

endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
wp_reset_query();
```

replace `YOUR_CUSTOMPOST_TYPE` with your post type,
what it does is finds posts of certain post type whose author is currently logged in user.

Currently it queries posts whose author is currently logged in user, you can list other users by using `get_users()`, [full description here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/), and set `'author' => get_current_user_id()` to `'author' => $ID_OF_USER`